# CTparental installation giving errors on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install CTparental on Ubuntu 20.04 by following the guide below and I got the error "Connection refused" at the last step of the guide when I try to go to http://my-server-ip

I would love to know how to fix this or what should I do to be able to access after I am done with the setup.

Thank you.

Here is the guide I mentioned above:

https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-install-ctparental-on-ubuntu-20-04

Here is a screenshot of the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8dMJ.png

Comment: Check your web server logs.

Comment: Check that your service is actually running on the port that you expect it to be on. `netstat -ltunp`